# How to extend the jPlayerPlaylist class to create a subclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

I'm new to extending JavaScript classes, but I've had experience with extending classes in other languages in the past, so I know the general ideas. I'm having trouble extending the jPlayerPlaylist class that I use for my site. I created a separate js file called `my_player.js` that I include in my site. The file has the following contents...

```
var MyPlaylist = jPlayerPlaylist.extend({
    init: function(selectors, playlist, functions){
        console.log("Initializing!");
        this._super(selectors, playlist, functions);        
    }
});
```

The jPlayerPlaylist class is located on my server at [this link](http://www.startingtofeelit.com/js/mobile/jplayer_playlist.js), and it has been minimized which doesn't help my comprehension of how to get this to work. Also, I made sure to include this javascript file before `my_player.js`, so that should not be an issue.

To construct a jPlayerPlaylist object, you pass it three arrays, so I tried to mimic this in my code that I showed above, but even just including this js file without even trying to initialize it, I get an Uncaught TypeError in my console that says `"Uncaught TypeError: Object {WHOLE JAVASCRIPT} has no method 'extend'"` where `WHOLE JAVASCRIPT` is just a print out of the jPlayerPlaylist code.

Anyone have any ideas?